# Lithium battery charger and balancer circuit (or IC)

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, charge, lithium, balancing

I am working on a project which sould **charge** and **balance** 4 to 6 (maybe 8 in future) serial connected lithium cell batteries (~4000 mAh capacity) with about 4A of charge current.

First I looked for IC which can do this anything and communicates through I2C. But I realized that **this is not that simple**.

I found this great application note:
http://www.cypress.com/file/70891/download

I divided the project into two parts:

**THE CHARGE CIRCUIT:**

My planes are build a charge circuit from this document (highlighted with red)[image]

Also I made some simulation on this circuit changing the duty cycle of 100 kHz PWM signal changes the charging current. With 60 % duty cycle I get about 4.5A (but this of course is a function of many things).
[image: With about 60% duty cycle I get 4.5A current]

The microcontroller will get feedback from this charge current (with INA169) and it will change the duty cycle of the PWM signal to achive desired CC and CV charging.

**THE BALANCE CIRCUIT:**

For balancing you need to measure very precisely cell voltages (you need many resistor dividers), turn on/off balancer FETs, this is a so many parts, so I decided to go for dedicated IC with integrated FETs and with I2C communication.
I guess 50 - 100 mA for balancing current per cells will be enough. I choose the BQ76925 or ISL92408.

---

The batteries will be high quality well cell matched. Its needed to charge them in 1 hours and fully balance them in about 2-3 hours more.

My question for larger experts will these things work together?

**UPDATE1:**
Bruce Abbott: Sry, Yes I mean ISL94208

Andy aka: Thanks for your suggestion. That is what I need. Now it looks like I will use LTC6811-2. LTC knows everything what I need.

My other idea for balancing is use free pins of STM32 F0 or F3 MCU (12 or 14 bit ADC) with resistor dividers (e.g. for 4th cell 1k : 5k resistors). What precision can I achieve with this configuration? +/-10 mV is enough, I think.

Comment: Why not use a Buck Boost topology? You will be able to charge you battery from a wider input voltage. i know that renesas have plenty ICs for Buck-boost battery charger. You can baseline on what they are doing.

Comment: [Multicell monitor and balancer chip](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6812-1.pdf)

Comment: Can't find any info on ISL92408. Do you mean [ISL94208](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/www/doc/datasheet/isl94208.pdf)?

Comment: Is this a special project you intent to mandatory do ? Otherwise, you can simply buy a BMS for the number of cells you need.

Comment: Yes, its a special project.